# How do I fix this code so that it doesn't take out vowels that are consecutive of one another?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Hey guys so I'm writing a code for text message abbreviations and these are the following criteria:

- Spaces are maintained, and each word is encoded individually. A word is a consecutive string of alphabetic characters.
- If the word is composed only of vowels, it is written exactly as in the original message.
- If the word has at least one consonant, write only the consonants that do not have another consonant immediately before them. Do not write any vowels.
- The letters considered vowels in these rules are 'a', 'e', 'i', 'o' and 'u'. All other letters are considered consonants.

I have written a code and checked it but it is failing for the condition where if the word is composed only of vowels, it is written exactly as in the original message. My code currently is taking out all of the vowels. Like for this example, "aeiou bcdfghjklmnpqrstvwxyz" the code should return "aeiou b"
I tried using another helper function to determine when a word is all vowels but it isn't working. Any suggestions on how to implement something that could make this work? Thanks!

```
def Vowel(x):
    vowels = "a" "e" "i" "o" "u"
    value = 0
    for ch in x:
        if x == vowels:
            value = value + 1
        return value

def isVowel(phrase):
    vowel = "a" "e" "i" "o" "u"
    value = 0
    for ch in phrase:
        if ch in vowel:
            value = value + 1
    return value

def noVowel(ch):
    vowel = "a" "e" "i" "o" "u"
    value = 0
    for i in ch:
        if ch not in vowel:
            value = value + 1
    return value

def transform(word):
    before = 'a'
    answer = ""
    for ch in word:
        if Vowel(ch):
            answer += ch
        if noVowel(ch) and isVowel(before):
            answer += ch
        before = ch
    return answer

def getMessage(original):
    trans = ""
    for word in original.split():
        trans = trans + " " + transform(word)
        trans = trans.strip()
    return trans

if __name__ == '__main__':
    print(getMessage("aeiou b"))
```

Comment: What would `jjjjopppddjk` return?... note the `o` in the word. Would this return `jp` or `j p` or `nothing` because it is a mix of vowels and consonants.

Comment: You have several functions that you can test independently, also see "Test-Driven Development (TDD)". Also, what is the output you receive from above program and the one you expect? In other words, provide a [mcve]! As a new user, also read [ask] and take the [tour]. Lastly, find a video tutorial that shows how to step through your code with a debugger. It should be easy to find the wrong turn it takes that way!

Answer (score 0):

Your three Vowel-functions are all using a disfunctional for-loop and are highly redundant. Also `Vowel()` would always return 0, as x may never be a tuple of five vowels.

You would need only one function that just returns `True` if the character is a vowel and `False` if it is not. Then, you can use this function in the if-blocks in `transform`:

```
def Vowel(x):
    vowels = ["a","e","i","o","u"]
    return x.lower() in vowels ## True if x is a vowel (upper or lower case)

def transform(word):
    before = 'a'
    answer = ""
    for ch in word:
        if Vowel(ch):
            answer += ch
        if not Vowel(ch) and Vowel(before):
            answer += ch
        before = ch
    return answer
```

Answer (score 0):

You have not identified what to do with words that have both consonants and vowels...if you provide a few more example inputs and outputs, I might decide to change my code, but this is what I have come up with so far.

I have used **regex**:
`(\b[aeiou]*\b)` : finds vowel only words
`([bcdfghjklmnpqrstvwxyz]*)` : looks for groups of consonants.

The `for-loop` : helps to return the vowel-only words, or the first letter of the consonant groups.

```py
import re

strings_to_test = ["aeiou bcdfghjklmnpqrstvwxyz ae hjgfd a",
                   "gg jjjjopppddjk eaf"]

pattern = re.compile(r"(\b[aeiou]*\b)|([bcdfghjklmnpqrstvwxyz]*)")

for line in strings_to_test:
    results = []
    match_list = pattern.findall(line)
    
    for m in match_list:
        if m[0]:
            # word of vowels found
            results.append(m[0])
        elif m[1]:
            #consonants found
            results.append(m[1][0])
            
    print(results)
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
['aeiou', 'b', 'ae', 'h', 'a']
['g', 'j', 'p', 'f']
```